# Django 2 ModelFormSet not submitting new entries

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a very simple Django grocery list app that I am using to learn the framework, and I'm using a modelformset to display/edit/add items in the list.  The problem I am having is that when I attempt to POST changes to the formset, it fails the .is_valid() condition.  formset.errors response is  **[{'id': ['This field is required.']}, {}]**, but all documentation/web lore says to not mess with the autogenerated id field, so I'm not sure why it is not working/why the ID field is not being generated.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Grocery(models.Model):
    itemName = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    itemQuantity = models.IntegerField()
    itemChecked = models.BooleanField(default = False, blank = False, null = False)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Grocery

class GroceryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Grocery
        fields = ['itemName', 'itemQuantity', 'itemChecked']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.forms import modelformset_factory

from .models import Grocery
from .forms import GroceryForm

def index(request):

    GroceryFormSet = modelformset_factory(Grocery,
    form=GroceryForm, 
    can_order=True,
    can_delete=True,
    )

    formset = GroceryFormSet(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(formset.errors)

        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()

    context = {
        'formset': formset,
        }

    return render(request, "Lister/index.html", context)
```

index.html

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Grocery Thing</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Got it?</th>
            <th>Change Order</th>
            <th>Delete?</th>

         </tr>
        {% for form in formset %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form.itemName }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.itemQuantity }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.itemChecked }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.ORDER }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.DELETE }}</td>
         </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
</form>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using formset you will need to include id field in your template:
[As seen at the end of this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-the-formset-in-the-template)
Edited to add a quick quote: 'Notice how we need to explicitly render {{ form.id }}. This ensures that the model formset, in the POST case, will work correctly. (This example assumes a primary key named id. If you’ve explicitly defined your own primary key that isn’t called id, make sure it gets rendered.)'

Comment: Ugggh I looked at that page until my eyes bled and somehow I missed that.  Working now, thank you so much!